# How to connect a signal between classes in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

I have very common question but it is not easy for me.

I'm trying to connect a PyQt signal from the `MainWindow` class to the `CheckExcel` class, but It doesn't work. I think some of people know how to do this, but some of them do not. Most people who doesn't know pointed out the code... but please don't do it. My point is how could I connect this?

Here is some code below:

```
class CheckExcel(QtCore.QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    updateLab = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    running = False

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckExcel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.progPercent = 0
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()

        try:
            while self.running == True:

                self.updated.emit(int(self.progPercent))
                self.updateLab.emit(str(va_TC))

                print(self.progPercent)

        except :
            print('Excel is not executed')

            CheckExcel().run()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def startBtnClicked(self):

        self.chk_excel = CheckExcel(self)
        self.chk_excel.start()

        self.chk_excel.updated.connect(self.updateValue)
        self.chk_excel.updateLab.connect(self.updateLabel)

    def updateValue(self, data):
        self.progressBar.setValue(data)

    def updateLabel(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The signals in your code example are all defined and connected correctly, and will work as expected. You have not explained what the problem is. What were you expecting to happen, and what happened instead? What errors did you see?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes you are right. It works! but My problem was when I opened more than 2 excel files  signal connection is disconnected.

Comment: To do that, you'd need a separate progress-bar, label and thread for each file you loaded.

Comment: like how?? how to separate progress-bar, label? I tried it. but doesn't work

Comment: Are you trying to two files at the same time, or one after the other?

Comment: @ekhumoro I tired one after the other